# In Bland Altman Analysis, does it make sense to have bias as a primary endpoint, but 95% LoAs as a secondary endpoint?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-visualization

In the context of Bland Altman analysis, is it justifiable to take a mean difference as a primary endpoint, but the 95% limits of agreement as a secondary endpoint?

My understanding is that in B&A analysis, it's actually the LoAs that are more important because bias can be adjusted for post hoc, but the LoA spread would remain the same.

Comment: You really need to tell us some of the context! What is your application?